# How to ignore the usage in test code when finding usage of some method or class

Tags: intellij-idea

In IDEA, I would ask how to ignore test code when finding usage of some method or class.

When I use `Find Usage` to find where a method is used, a lot of places in the test code that use the method are queried out

I would ask how to ignore the usage in the test code and only get`useful` usage.

Comment: It's possible to select needed scope in "Find Usages" popup.